# PIVOT query on Distinct records

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have below table:

```
------------------------------------------------------
| Id    Code  percentage  name  name1   activity     |
-----------------------------------------------------
| 1   Prashant  43.43    James  James_  Running      |
| 1   Prashant  70.43    Sam    Sam_    Cooking      |
| 1   Prashant  90.34    Lisa   Lisa_   Walking      |
| 1   Prashant  0.00     James  James_  Stealing     |
| 1   Prashant  0.00     James  James_  Lacking      |
| 1   Prashant  73       Sam     Sam_   Cooking 1    |
------------------------------------------------------
```

The problem is, due to `MAX` function it is ignoring `0.00` value with Column name Name1 of `Lacking`

**Expected Result:**

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Id  Code        James    James_  Sam        Sam_    Lisa      Lisa_
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1   Prashant    Running  43.43  Cooking     3.43    Walking   90.34
1   Prashant    Stealing 0.0    Cooking 1   73      NULL      NULL
1   Prashant    Lacking  0.0    NULL        NULL    NULL      NULL
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The PIVOT Query what I tried:

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @DynamicPivotQuery  = N'SELECT Id,Code,James,James_,Sam,Sam_,Lisa,Lisa_
    INTO ##TempPivot 
    FROM A
    PIVOT(MAX(activity)
          FOR name IN (James,Sam,Lisa)) AS PVTTable PIVOT
          (
          MAX(percentage)
          FOR name1 IN (James_,Sam_,Lisa_)) AS PVTTable1'


EXECUTE(@DynamicPivotQuery) 

SELECT * 
INTO #RESULT 
FROM ##TempPivot


SELECT * 
FROM #RESULT
```

Sample query to generate data:

```
CREATE TABLE A
(
  Id NVARCHAR(10),
  Code NVARCHAR(MAX),
  percentage NVARCHAR(MAX),
  name NVARCHAR(MAX),
  name1 NVARCHAR(MAX),
  activity NVARCHAR(MAX)
)


INSERT INTO A VALUES (1,'Prashant',43.43,'James','James_','Running')
INSERT INTO A VALUES (1,'Prashant',3.43,'Sam','Sam_','Cooking')
INSERT INTO A VALUES (1,'Prashant',90.34,'Lisa','Lisa_','Walking')
INSERT INTO A VALUES (1,'Prashant',0.00,'James','James_','Stealing')
INSERT INTO A VALUES (1,'Prashant',0.00,'James','James_','Lacking')
INSERT INTO A VALUES (1,'Prashant',73,'Sam','Sam_','Cooking 1')
```

Comment: Do you have to use a temp table to get your results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a ROW_NUMBER() into the mix, your pivot will be able to retain the association between activities and percentages.

```
;with cte as 
(
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by name order by percentage desc) ROWNUM
    from A
),
cte2 as
(
    SELECT Id,Code,ROWNUM,James,James_,Sam,Sam_,Lisa,Lisa_
    FROM cte
    PIVOT(MAX(activity)
          FOR name IN (James,Sam,Lisa)) AS PVTTable PIVOT
          (
          MAX(percentage)
          FOR name1 IN (James_,Sam_,Lisa_)) AS PVTTable1
)
select Id, Code, MAX(James) James, MAX(James_) James_, MAX(Sam) Sam, MAX(Sam_) Sam_, MAX(Lisa) Lisa, MAX(Lisa_) Lisa_
from cte2
group by Id, Code, ROWNUM
```

Returns:

```
Id  Code        James       James_  Sam         Sam_    Lisa    Lisa_
1   Prashant    Running     43.43   Cooking 1   73      Walking 90.34
1   Prashant    Stealing    0.00    Cooking     3.43    NULL    NULL
1   Prashant    Lacking     0.00    NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL
```

The idea is, in thefirst common table expression, you transform the A table to this:

```
Id  Code        percentage  name    name1   activity    ROWNUM
1   Prashant    43.43       James   James_  Running     1
1   Prashant    0.00        James   James_  Stealing    2
1   Prashant    0.00        James   James_  Lacking     3
1   Prashant    90.34       Lisa    Lisa_   Walking     1
1   Prashant    73          Sam     Sam_    Cooking 1   1
1   Prashant    3.43        Sam     Sam_    Cooking     2
```

And throughout the remaining query, the ROWNUM column just acts to bind the percentage value to the activity.

Making it dynamic is easy once you have a working query. Just replace all the dynamic parts (in this case, comma-delimited lists of names, right?) with variables. Something like this:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
declare @name_concat nvarchar(max)
declare @name1_concat nvarchar(max)
declare @select_aggs nvarchar(max)
select @name_concat = STUFF((select distinct ',' + quotename(name) from A order by 1 for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')
select @name1_concat = STUFF((select distinct ',' + quotename(name1) from A order by 1 for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')

;with cte_all_names as (
    select name from A
    union all 
    select name1 from A
)
select @select_aggs = STUFF((select distinct ',MAX(' + quotename(name) + ') ' + quotename(name) from cte_all_names order by 1 for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')

select @sql = '
;with cte as 
(
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by name order by percentage desc) ROWNUM
    from A
),
cte2 as
(
    SELECT Id,Code,ROWNUM,' + @name_concat + ',' + @name1_concat + '
    FROM cte
    PIVOT(MAX(activity)
          FOR name IN (' + @name_concat + ')) AS PVTTable PIVOT
          (
          MAX(percentage)
          FOR name1 IN (' + @name1_concat + ')) AS PVTTable1
)
select Id, Code, ' + @select_aggs + '
from cte2
group by Id, Code, ROWNUM
'

exec sp_executesql @sql
```