# How to check if trip for particular semester is set between from date and to date

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

Here I want to check that if a trip for a particular semester is arranged between from date to date in previous table records.

Table Schema:

```
trip_from_date
trip_end_date
trip_sem_id
trip_dress_code
```

Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [db].[pro_1] var duration, 
  @Trip_sem_id    int, 
  @Trip_from_date date, 
  @Trip_to_date   date 
AS 
  BEGIN 
    SELECT * 
    FROM   isrp_trip_master 
    WHERE  trip_sem_id=@Trip_sem_id 
    AND    duration BETWEEN trip_from_date=@Trip_from_date AND    trip_to_date=@Trip_to_date 
    AND    isnull(trip_is_delete,0)=0 
  END
```

I expect a table with all field which fulfills my condition

Comment: How to ask:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53372997/pivot-query-on-distinct-records

Comment: Please provide the sample data, current output and expected output

Comment: The code is clearly T-SQL so I added the SQL Server tag.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have somehow already checked that `trip_from_date` < `trip_to_date` (`CHECK` constraint):

```
trip_from_date >= @Trip_From_date AND trip_to_date <= @Trip_to_date
```

Answer (score 0):

To add more details from lau's answer are you expecting to do something like this

```
declare  @Trip_from_date date= '1 Jan 2018'
declare  @Trip_to_date   date = '23 Jan 2018'
--Check to see if the dates selected falls within the required range
select * from isrp_trip_master where @Trip_from_date >= trip_from_date and     trip_end_date >=@Trip_to_date`
```