# Apply multiple filters one at a time in query

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]I want to apply filter in SQL query but in any order. What i mean is that if i have three parameters name para1, para2 and para3 and i want to apply only para1 and para3 parameters but do not want to apply para2 parameter in query or I want to apply only para3 parameter but don't want to apply para1 and para2 parameters in query.

In attached image if i want to apply filer on assigned_user_id and do not want to apply filer on Status or Dept column than result should show record filter on first parameter only.

Please help.

Comment: Need some sample data and expected output with your try! Check this [sample question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53372997/7124761)

Comment: @PrashantPimpale if any solution is already available in stack overflow please share link.

Comment: Question is not clear! Request you to read the question again!

Comment: How that *para1 2 3 looks* like? Where do you want to pass it? Is it in Stored Procedure? AdHoc query? What you will get by passing those parameters (in terms of results)?

Comment: as per your question, It seems you apply parameter using dynamic query based on condition.

Comment: @PrashantPimpale yes it is stored procedure which takes three parameters.

Comment: @BhargavJPatel how to write dynamic query and apply filters of those parameters which do have value. If a parameter don't have value than it should not be applied.

Comment: @SyedImranShah Then we need it: Atleast with sample data!

Comment: @PrashantPimpale image is added in question above.

Comment: Check this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415582/how-can-i-use-optional-parameters-in-a-t-sql-stored-procedure

Comment: [Why images are not good while posting a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @PrashantPimpale thank you for sharing useful link. It resolve my issue.

Comment: @SyedImranShah Welcome!

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is to have a stored proc where you pass 3 params p1,p2,p3, and one or more of them might be null. I will leave how to pass null for an unused parameter from whatever your caller application is up to you.

The way to do the sql selection, is this.

```
where
   (@p1 is null null or column1=@p1)
   and (@p2 is null or column2=@p2)
   and (@p3 is null or column3=@p3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let ruby language for example. If you have any expressions to filter, you can manipulate with its as a strings:

```
conditions = {
  para2: '> 0',
  para3: '= 0',
  para4: '!= 100500',
}
```

so, you can collect them to where clause:

```
where_clause_rules = conditions.map do |key, value|
  "#{key} #{conditions[key]}"
end

where_clause = "WHERE #{where_clause_rules.join(' AND ')}"
```

and you have a result:

```
WHERE para2 > 0 AND para3 = 0 AND para4 != 100500
```

add this string to your sql:

```
SELECT * 
FROM your_table
#{where_clause}
```

you give result:

```
SELECT * 
FROM your_table
WHERE para2 > 0 AND para3 = 0 AND para4 != 100500
```

run sql:

```
Activerecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

enjoy

Comment: This will not help!