# Calculate Average of the largest values in multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, max, average

I have this table

```
[1|Sub1|Mark1|Sub2|Mark2|Subj3|Mark3|...]
[2|JSP |85   |ASP |70   |PHP  |95   |...]
```

I need the average Marks of the two highest subjects?

For example

### avg(Mark1,Mark3);

Comment: [Check how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53372997/pivot-query-on-distinct-records)

Comment: Are you interested in SQL Server? MySQL? Or both?

Comment: I need both of them.

Comment: First, fix your broken schema; a database table is not a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

May be are you asking this?

```
SELECT ID,
  (SELECT AVG(v) 
   FROM (VALUES (Mark1), (Mark2), (Mark3), (Mark4), (Mark5)) AS value(v)) as [AverageMarks]
FROM Table1
```

If you are looking for only Average of 2 highest subjects among 3 subjects then try this.

```
SELECT ID,
  (SELECT (SUM(v)-MIN(V))/2
   FROM (VALUES (Mark1), (Mark2), (Mark3)) AS value(v)) as [AverageMarks]
FROM Table1
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5915718ef7765d91215b99db60810e92)**

Comment: [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) strongly recommends only answering well-asked questions.

Comment: Thank you @VigneshKumarA So what if I only need the Avg of largest three only?

Comment: Amount 5 subject, do you want to find the average of highest 3 subjects?

Comment: Please edit your question and update all these information. Also post the sample data.

Comment: Be clear on your ask. You want to find average of highest 2 subject or 3 subjects.. @AbdifatahAbdilahi

Comment: @VigneshKumarA  highest 2 subjects.

Comment: Updated my answer. check it out

Comment: Thank you @VigneshKumarA you helped me a lot.
Is it Same scenario if there is 7 subjects and I  want the avg of  highest 5.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201996/discussion-between-abdifatah-abdilahi-and-vignesh-kumar-a).

Comment: @VigneshKumarA are you there please what if my subjects are 7 and i want highest 5.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXIST my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(subject CHAR(3) PRIMARY KEY
,mark INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
('JSP',85),
('ASP',70),
('PHP',95);   

SELECT AVG(a.mark)
  FROM 
     ( SELECT mark FROM my_table ORDER BY mark DESC LIMIT 2 ) a;

+-------------+
| AVG(a.mark) |
+-------------+
|     90.0000 |
+-------------+
```

Comment: I think, you've missed the table structure and original ask of the user !!

Comment: @VigneshKumarA No. The OP has missed the point of what a relational database is, and how it works. Our role is not to provide sticking plasters for these kinds of errors, but to correct them.

Comment: First of all he want to find Average among columns not rows

Comment: ...which is not something you would ever need or want to do with well-formatted data.