# aggregate dynamic column values mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, pivot, aggregate-functions

I have following `task` table:

```
id  |  client_id  |  user_id  |  designation_id   |  total_hours
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1   |  14         |  134      |  1                |  4
2   |  14         |  135      |  2                |  1
3   |  15         |  136      |  3                |  3
4   |  16         |  137      |  4                |  4.5
```

And `designations` table:

```
id  |  title
------------------------
1   | Cloud Analyst
2   | Data Analyst
3   | Data QA Analyst
4   | Project Manager
.
.
```

And I have a stored procedure that pivots each records in `designations` table into `columns` (dynamic):

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS clientWiseHoursReport;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `clientWiseHoursReport`(IN `start_date` DATETIME, IN `end_date` DATETIME)
BEGIN

SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len=4294967295;
SET @SQL = NULL;
SET @start_date = DATE(start_date);
SET @end_date = DATE(end_date);

    SELECT
    COALESCE(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
    '(CASE WHEN tsk.designation_id = "',id,'" THEN total_hours ELSE NULL END) AS `',title,'`'
    ) ORDER BY title
), '0 as `NoMatchingRows`') INTO @SQL

        FROM `designations`
        WHERE is_pivotable = 1;            

    SET @SQL 
    = CONCAT
    (
    '
        SELECT cnt.name as Client, concat(usr.firstname," ",usr.lastname) as Name, ttype.name as "Project Type", task_details as "Task Detail", ', @SQL, '
        FROM
        task as tsk
        LEFT JOIN client cnt
            ON tsk.client_id = cnt.id
        LEFT JOIN task_type ttype
            ON tsk.task_type_id = ttype.id
        LEFT JOIN users usr
            ON tsk.user_id = usr.id
        WHERE ((DATE(task_completion) BETWEEN "',@start_date,'" AND "',@end_date,'") OR
            (DATE(assigned_date) BETWEEN "',@start_date,'" AND "',@end_date,'") OR
            (DATE(task_deadline) BETWEEN "',@start_date,'" AND "',@end_date,'"))            
    '
    );

PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;


END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

This gives the result as:

```
client  |  user  |  Cloud Analyst  |  Data Analyst  |  Data QA Analyst  |  Project Manager
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
14      |  134   |  4              |                |                   |          
14      |  135   |                 |  1             |                   |
15      |  136   |                 |                |   3               |
16      |  137   |                 |                |                   |   4.5
```

What I am trying to get is `SUM` of each dynamic `designation` columns grouped by `client_id`.

LIKE :

```
client  |  user  |  Cloud Analyst  |  Data Analyst  |  Data QA Analyst  |  Project Manager
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
14      |  134   |  4              |                |                   |          
14      |  135   |  0.5            |                |                   |
14      |  null  |  4.5            |                |                   |
```

If, say, columns were known, it would be:

```
.
.
UNION ALL
SELECT client, NULL, NULL.., SUM('Cloud Analyst') as c1, SUM('Data Analyst') as d1....
```

something like that..

But I got stuck with the `dynamic` case.

I found a [similar solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41609820/dynamic-pivot-table-with-column-and-row-totals-in-sql-server-2012) but in `sql-server` and I couldn't crack it.

Hoping someone could help me with this.